# CSS gradient: define width in pixels

Tags: css

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpftqc26/

A CSS gradient, starts black from left, turns into red, then back to black again. Really simple.

Is there any way I can make the red part 500px wide and the black parts fill the screen, whatever the resolution? With red in the middle, just like in the fiddle.

**Is there a way do define a width in pixels, between color stops, in a CSS gradient?**

**Code:**

```
.test_gradient {
background: 
linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      #000000,
      #000000 20%,
      #ff0000 20%,
      #ff0000 80%,
      #000000 80%
    );
```

Comment: Is there a reason for it to have gradient?

Comment: remember `calc` function. Do you do `... #ff0000 calc(20% + 10px), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that black part was flexible and red part was fixed you could use something like this:

```
html{height:100%;}
.test_gradient {
    background: #000000;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
.test_gradient:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:500px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    background:#f00;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nstf25jv/)

Comment: I think *must* is the wrong word here. Clearly *could* would be a better choice as there is definitely more than one solution.

Comment: Thank you!! Will do some tests!

Comment: @Phlume, sry, my english is bad

Comment: no worries. It's a working solution, just a comment on the restrictive "must". Some beginner users may find that as the ultimate solution and cease looking for new ways to resolve the issue.

Comment: Changed this to the accepted answer, after much testing in a complex webpage. Using calc generates minor problems, this is a better solution.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. you can do this with hard pixels points and the use of the calc function.
Just set them as such:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpftqc26/9/

CSS:

```
.test_gradient {
background: 
linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      #000000 0px, /* Starting point */
      #000000 calc(50% - 250px), /* End black point */
      #ff0000 calc(50% - 250px), /* Starting red point */
      #ff0000 calc(50% + 250px), /* End red point */
      #000000 calc(50% + 250px), /* Starting black point */
      #000000 100% /* End black point */
    );
```

Comment: Phlume, amazing idea! Resolution independent. Will check browser support for calc and will be back with an accepted answer in a few hours!

Comment: may need to vendor prefix it, asit is emerging css so use with caution. Some dev notes about it are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it, without using calc(), is to use 2 different gradients

```
.test_gradient {
background-image: 
linear-gradient( to left,  #ff0000 0px,  #ff0000 250px,  #000000 100px), linear-gradient( to right,   red 0px,  #ff0000 250px,  #000000 100px);

background-size: 50.1% 1000px;
background-position: top left, top right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

One goes to the right, the other to the left, and each one has half the total width

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpftqc26/10/)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I can't think of how to do it with only CSS gradients and a single element.

Given your example, and assuming an extra div is ok, then here's an alternative approach without gradients (http://jsfiddle.net/jpftqc26/2/):

HTML

```
<body class="background">
    <div class="foreground"/>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.background {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.foreground {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This produces the same effect, uses one additional element, and provides a red foreground that will grow to a max of 500px wide--beyond that it is all black on both sides.  If you want the red to *always* be 500px wide then just remove the `max-width` rule and change `width` to 500px.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best solution, without adding any html element, is to use an image as background:

```
.test_gradient {
    background: url('http://s14.postimg.org/zf0kd84lt/redline.jpg') repeat-y #000 center top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Monteduro/jpftqc26/3/

Comment: If you're going to use an image you may as well embed it to avoid the extra request -- http://jsfiddle.net/jpftqc26/7/

`.test_gradient {
    background:  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAADElEQVQI12P4z8AAAAMBAQAY3Y2wAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat-y #000 center top;
    background-size: 500px;
}`

Comment: op specifically asks for a gradient in css